Discrepancy between MathOverflow logo and this site's logo
There is a slight difference between the sizes of the boxes in the MO logo and the Meta.MO logo. The MO logo's box is slightly longer and the gap in the rightmost side is slightly less tall. The difference is best seen when switching back and forth between an MO tab and a Meta.MO tab on the front page.
